# C -- Filling char * using a loop and index --- NOT WORKING

Tags: c, string, loops, indexing, char

This chunk of code is part of a function to convert a decimal number into binary, placing it in a specific index of char instBin[33] that was created and passed by reference by the calling function. It passes in the decimal number, the number of binary digits you'd like (appending extra 0's to the front of a given bin number). I've been fiddling with this for a while now and I can't get it to place 0's and 1's into the array. I've gotten it all the way down to realizing that instBin[i] = '1'; just isn't working at all -- when I print instBin, nothing has happened. I've looked at other examples doing this type of thing, but it seems that giving an array of characters a variable when selecting an index should work... Any thoughts why mine isn't?

```
int printBin(int num, int numBits, int startIndex, char * instBin){
    int r, i; /* r for remainder, i for index */
const int FAIL = 0;
i = startIndex + numBits; /* start indexing at end of current segment */
while (num > 0)
{
    /* as long as i >= startIndex, we can still add to array */
    if (i >= startIndex){
        r = num % 2; /* find the remainder */
        if (r == 1)
            instBin[i] = '1';
        else /* r == 0 */
            instBin[i] = '0';
        num /= 2; /* then actually divide the number */
        i--;
    }
    else /* num is too big to fit in given number of bits */
    return FAIL;
}
/* return the 1 for success*/
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Please show the function definition line (the one with the return type, function name, and parameter declarations)!  It's good to have FAIL defined; why not define PASS or SUCCESS or whatever too?  On Unix, system functions often return 0 for success — the opposite of the convention you're using.

Comment: tip: you can write simply `instBin[i]='0'+num%2;`. And comments like `/* find the remainder */` do not add any information to your code.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks! Oh and for Sergi0, instBin was defined as such: char instBin[33]; //one spot for a null byte

Comment: I think this code is working fine, as long as the parameters are OK. How do you call it? How do you print the contents of the array? if it is a string, you'll need to add `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: I put '\0' at instBin[32] in the calling function. Its just when it gets to "instBin[i] = '1';" literally nothing happens to instBin, if I put a printf after it, it shows nothing. adding to instBin using an immediate (1, 2, 3) is fine, but when I use this variable in this situation it isn't doing anything.

Comment: please put here the full context, including your printing statements. I don't see an actual error here (and seems like nobody else here does). Is the `char*` points to an allocated memory?

Comment: The logic seems to work fine if i call `printBin(num,31,0,bin)` and then print the number from *index 0 to 31*. Did you set/cleared the `instBin` variable before calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems. The first is a fencepost error. Assuming your intent is that the most significant bit will be put into the buffer at the `startIndex`, you need to start with `i = startIndex + numBits - 1`. Think through an example with `numBits = 1` if you need convincing of this.

The second problem is that when the number is small enough to need leading zeros, your loop doesn't provide them. It provides one digit at a time until the number hits 0, then stops. You need a second loop after the main loop, to add the zeros. If you look at the value of `i` after the main loop, it tells you where the main loop stopped, so you can finish the job like this:

```
while(i >= startIndex)
    instBin[i--] = '0';
```